# How can I build a linux kernel module in Android 9?

Tags: android, tcp, kernel

What should I do to build a Linux kernel module in Android 9? To be more specific, How can I use different TCP stacks in Android 9?

I was told to try different TCP stacks on Android 9 device to do a comparison. I did some research and find that Linux kernel modules can be built standalone, but this feature is no longer supported in Android nowadays. So any ideas how I can get this done.